# sql multiple outer joins on multiple fields

Tags: sql, outer-join

SQL beginner here.
I am trying to outer-join one table (pgm_update) to two other tables (family and family_act_visits). A pgm_update record may correspond to a family record or a family_act_visits record or neither; my results should return data for all three cases. Both of some bad architecture, the joins have to be on multiple columns. Each of these individual queries works, but I haven't been able to combine them into a single query.

```
SELECT p.last_name_wo, p.activity, p.participation, fav.* 
FROM family_act_visits fav 
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p ON fav.folks_fk=p.folks_fk and fav.activity=p.activity 
    JOIN activities a on p.activity=a.activity 
WHERE p.participation in ('c','a') and a.act_start_date>current_date()

SELECT p.last_name_wo, p.activity, p.participation, f.* 
FROM family f 
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p ON f.folks_fk=p.folks_fk and f.activity=p.activity 
JOIN activities a on p.activity=a.activity 
WHERE p.participation in ('c','a') and a.act_start_date>current_date()
```

One of my attempts at the full query is:

```
SELECT p.last_name_wo, p.activity, p.participation, fav.* 
FROM family_act_visits fav, family f
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p ON fav.folks_fk=p.folks_fk and fav.activity=p.activity
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p2 ON f.folks_fk=p2.folks_fk and f.activity=p2.activity
JOIN activities a on p.activity=a.activity
WHERE p.participation in ('c','a') and a.act_start_date>current_date()
```

This gets the error message "Unknown column 'fav.folks_fk' in 'on clause'"
Hope this long post contains all the info needed....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `JOIN`ing on multiple conditions does not indicate poor design.

Are you sure you want a [RIGHT JOIN?](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)

Perhaps you are looking for [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Your query is a bit complicated, and it includes a [CROSS JOIN](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php), perhaps unintentionally?

Perhaps you just want to [UNION ALL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) which allows you to append datasets having the same shape....

```
SELECT 
    p.last_name_wo
    ,p.activity
    ,p.participation
    ,fav.* 
FROM 
    family_act_visits fav 
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p 
    ON fav.folks_fk=p.folks_fk 
    AND fav.activity=p.activity 
JOIN activities a 
    ON p.activity=a.activity 
WHERE 
    p.participation IN ('c','a') 
    AND a.act_start_date>current_date()
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    p.last_name_wo
    ,p.activity
    ,p.participation
    ,f.* 
FROM 
    family f 
RIGHT JOIN pgm_update p 
    ON f.folks_fk=p.folks_fk 
    AND f.activity=p.activity 
JOIN activities a 
    ON p.activity=a.activity 
WHERE 
    p.participation IN ('c','a') 
    AND a.act_start_date>current_date()
```

Comment: You can upvote helpful answers and accept answers which resolve your issue, thanks.